# Is the automatic deserialization in an HTTP bound Azure function considering locale specific information?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, json-deserialization

When I am calling my azure function with HTTP POST and a json body the deserialization is not working for a decimal as I expected.

I am hosting the azure function locally and in the request body I am transferring a json object with a decimal in it.

```
{
    "Receiver": {
        "Name1": "Mr. Homer Simpson",
        "AddressLine1": "742 Evergreen Terrace",
        "ZipCode": "AEED",
        "City": "Springfield",
        "CountryCode": "US"
    },
    "ReferenceNumber": "US1939383",
    "Weight": 4.2
}
```

```
    public class LabelInformation
    {
        public ParcelAddress? Receiver { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoice number. TODO Should be renamed.
        /// </summary>
        public string? ReferenceNumber { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Total weight of the parcel.
        /// </summary>
        public decimal? Weight { get; set; }
    }

    public class ParcelAddress
    {
        public string? Name1 { get; set; }
        public string? AddressLine1 { get; set; }
        public string? ZipCode { get; set; }
        public string? City { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Country 2 letter ISO code.
        /// </summary>
        public string? CountryCode { get; set; }
    }
```

```
        [FunctionName("GenerateLabelGLSFunctionHttpTrigger")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "label/gls")]
            LabelInformation info)
        {
             ...
        }
```

Changing the type of info to string and then manually deserialize the string works as expected.

```
        [FunctionName("GenerateLabelGLSFunctionHttpTrigger")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "label/gls")]
            string info)
        {
            var labelInformation = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LabelInformation>(info);

            _logger.LogInformation("create the label.");
            GlsSoap.ShipmentRequestData payload = _labelService.CreateShipmentRequestData(labelInformation);
```

The error I receive is

```
[09.10.2019 10:28:38] Executed 'GenerateLabelGLSFunctionHttpTrigger' (Failed, Id=90330456-1ac2-43f3-9285-ab2284b6c31f)
[09.10.2019 10:28:38] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: GenerateLabelGLSFunctionHttpTrigger. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Exception binding parameter 'info'. System.Private.CoreLib: Input string was not in a correct format.
[09.10.2019 10:28:38] fail: Host.Results[0]
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException: Exception while executing function: GenerateLabelGLSFunctionHttpTrigger ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Exception binding parameter 'info' ---> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.ParseSingle(ReadOnlySpan`1 value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
   at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToSingle(IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http.HttpTriggerAttributeBindingProvider.HttpTriggerBinding.ConvertValueIfNecessary(Object value, Type targetType) in C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions\src\WebJobs.Extensions.Http\HttpTriggerAttributeBindingProvider.cs:line 415
...
```

I expect the automatic deserialization **not to use locale information** (on my OS it is German - if I change to English everything is working as expected) for deserializing a decimal.

Or please explain me, why this should be good, as functions can be hosted on different locales and a caller to that function would need to know where the function is deployed to take into account the correct decimal seperator.

Comment: You say it works if you change it to a string, but you didn't post the declaration of the type you deserialize into. Can you show what you had, that failed? In particular I'm interested in the C# declaration of the property to hold the weight.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen: I have updated the description. Thanks!

Comment: Where is the code that declares a parameter named `test`?

Comment: @TomW sorry, I was renaming it to info during error analysis. I changed it in the description

Answer (score 0):

I see a lot of  declaration issues in your class definition:

Here is my code which worked perfectly:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace FunctionAppPostComplexObject
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] LabelInformation info,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            LabelInformation labelInformation = info;

            //_logger.LogInformation("create the label.");
            string name = "";// req.Query["name"];

            //string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
          //  dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
          //  name = name ?? data?.name;

            return name != null
                ? (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"Hello, {name}")
                : new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body");
        }

        public class LabelInformation
        {
            public ParcelAddress Receiver { get; set; }

            /// <summary>
            /// Invoice number. TODO Should be renamed.
            /// </summary>
            public string ReferenceNumber { get; set; }

            /// <summary>
            /// Total weight of the parcel.
            /// </summary>
            public decimal? Weight { get; set; }
        }

        public class ParcelAddress
        {
            public string Name1 { get; set; }
            public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
            public string ZipCode { get; set; }
            public string City { get; set; }
            /// <summary>
            /// Country 2 letter ISO code.
            /// </summary>
            public string CountryCode { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the value for info:

[image]

Check this and see if it helps.

Comment: I see on your system time that you are using english locale. That is my problem. If I change from German locale to English locale everything is working as expected.

Comment: i see what you are saying , its more of a localisation issue, let me check and get back.

Comment: In european server the decimal seperator is "," Try passing like "Weight": "4,2"  , it should work.

Comment: Yes, I know. But this is my issue. For me this is not working as expected. A client that is sending the request would have to know which locale is defined on the server-side.

Comment: simple approach for that would be to use string instead of decimal, would that work for you. In that case you don't need to worry.

Comment: No, because than it does not work the other way round. Sending "weight": "4,2" on an English locale leads to "42" after unmarshalling.

Answer (score 0):

Adapting from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62270924/163170) answer in order to override the serializer settings, you might try adding something like this to your function app project to tell the serializer to use the invariant culture:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(Configs.Startup))]

namespace Configs
{
    class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddMvcCore().AddNewtonsoftJson(x =>
            {
                x.SerializerSettings.Culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

If that doesn't work, it's probably because of [this](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Utilities/ConvertUtils.cs#L1271) custom Decimal converter, but the fact that it adapter to your locale makes me think the above will work.

**Update:** the above may have been supplanted in the .NET 5 era.  See [this post](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/5469#issuecomment-889622505).