# Access Json Serializer options to avoid serializing null in Azure Functions v3

Tags: c#, json, azure, json.net, azure-functions

How can I setup the serializer in Azure Functions to ignore nulls when serializing?

This is a v3 function

I have tried

```
        JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
        };
```

In the startup for my function

I am now starting to think that Newtonsoft isnt being used for json

How can I force Newtonsoft to be used?

Cheers

Paul

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set json serializer settings in asp.net core 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58392039/how-to-set-json-serializer-settings-in-asp-net-core-3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## 2023 edit

The various function (and MVC) versions have different ways of setting this up and may use Newtonsoft.Json or System.Text.Json

Links:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/5841#issuecomment-987168758

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62270924/5436889

test

## Original answer (older versions)

Adapted from [Add JSON Options In HTTP Triggered Azure Functions](https://medium.com/@ravindraa/add-json-options-in-http-triggered-azure-functions-d44b623de6e9)

#### Prerequisites

> You need ensure that all prerequisites are fulfilled as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#prerequisites)

From that docs page:

> Before you can use dependency injection, you must install the following NuGet packages:

> - Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions
> - Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions package version 1.0.28 or later
> - Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection (currently, only version 3.x and earlier supported)

Note:

> The guidance in this article applies only to C# class library functions, which run in-process with the runtime. This custom dependency injection model doesn't apply to .NET isolated functions, which lets you run .NET 5.0 functions out-of-process. The .NET isolated process model relies on regular ASP.NET Core dependency injection patterns.

#### Code

Add Startup class to your Azure Function Project as given below:

```cs
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(MyNamespace.Startup))]
namespace MyNamespace {
    public class Startup: FunctionsStartup {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder) {
            builder.Services.AddMvcCore().AddJsonFormatters().AddJsonOptions(options => {
                // Adding json option to ignore null values.
                options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

> This will set the JSON option to ignore null values.

Comment: This does not work in Functions V3 which is built on top of the ASP.Net core 3.0+

Comment: Is it a good practice to add MvcCore in Azure functions?

Comment: @Bat_Programmer if you have a way of configuring Json formatting _without_ adding MvcCore, then please share it. Otherwise if you _need_ Json formatting, then it seems like this is the only way, which makes 'good practice' irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

In a Functions V3 App I had to use the following having installed the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` NuGet package.

```
builder.Services.AddMvcCore().AddNewtonsoftJson(options => {
                // Adding json option to ignore null values.
                options.SerializerSettings.DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat;
});
```

Source: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/5841#issuecomment-987168758

Answer (score -1):

The accepted answer for this question does not work for Azure Functions v3+.
You can use version 3.0+ of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` package to setup the JSON serializer options.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62270924/5436889